# Do Spring MVC controller look for ids or names?

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, forms

If I have the following HTML form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/myFormHandler" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="fizz-id" name="fizz" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" id="buzz-id" name="buzz" value="6" />
</form>
```

(Notice no submit button). And then I have the following jQuery:

```
$("#someButton").click(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

Then on the server-side (Spring MVC controller), do the hidden field **ids** or **names** get sent to the handler method?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myFormHandler.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleMyForm(
    @RequestParam("fizz-id") String fizz,
    @RequestParam("buzz-id") String buzz) {

    // Should I be looking for "fizz-id" or "fizz"???

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it would be fizz (name).

Comment: Open the network tab on the browser debug tool, execute your code and check (in Chrome for example) the `Form Data` or `Query String Parameters` section on the `headers` tab. That will tell you exactly what is sent up and how it is named.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its the `name` attribute that is sent to the server, so in this case you should look for "fizz".

The `id` attribute is just used for client side interaction, it is not sent in the request to the server.

Comment: Here's a link to the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#submit-format

Answer (score 0):

with a post request ,it is the name attribute of a HTML element that is used to access it using request.getParameter.